# How to Add Rows Together Despite GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created a function that joins two tables together to retrieve the data necessary to complete the task. However, the functions RETURNS TABLE output gives a seperate column to each instance where the `FlightID` appears in the `FlightBooking` table.

How do I merge these rows together? And just add the reserved/cancelled columns together? And advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seatInformation(INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE(flightID INTEGER, MaxCapacity 
INTEGER, reserved_seats INTEGER, cancelled_seats INTEGER, available_Seats bigint) AS
$$
  SELECT f.flightID, f.MaxCapacity,
  (SELECT fb.NumSeats as reserved_seats WHERE fb.Status = 'r' LIMIT 1), 
  (SELECT fb.NumSeats as cancelled_seats WHERE fb.Status = 'c' LIMIT 1),
  MaxCapacity - SUM(fb.NumSeats)
  FROM Flight f INNER JOIN FlightBooking fb
  ON f.flightID = fb.flightID
  WHERE f.flightID = $1
  GROUP BY fb.NumSeats, fb.Status, f.flightID
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

[image: Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution may be to enclose your existing query as a table expression and then group it by `flightID`. For example:

```
select
  flightID,
  sum(MaxCapacity) as MaxCapacity,
  sum(rs) as reserved_seats,
  sum(cs) as cancelled_seats,
  sum(avs) as available_seats
from (
  SELECT f.flightID, f.MaxCapacity,
  (SELECT fb.NumSeats as reserved_seats WHERE fb.Status = 'r' LIMIT 1) as rs, 
  (SELECT fb.NumSeats as cancelled_seats WHERE fb.Status = 'c' LIMIT 1) as cs,
  MaxCapacity - SUM(fb.NumSeats) as avs
  FROM Flight f
  INNER JOIN FlightBooking fb ON f.flightID = fb.flightID
  WHERE f.flightID = $1
  GROUP BY fb.NumSeats, fb.Status, f.flightID
) x 
GROUP BY flightID
```

Comment: Now saying "return type mismatch in function declared to return record"?